# Any modern way to disable sort in Object.assign if objects has numeric keys?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

For example: [snippet img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHjki.jpg)

```
var a = {1: '1', 2: '2'}
var b = {3: '3', 4: '4'}

Object.assign({}, a, b)
> {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4"}

Object.assign({}, b, a)
> {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4"}
```

Is there way to disable sorting?

Comment: You should consider objects to be not sorted. Of you rely on the order of things, use arrays.

Comment: Object properties don't have an order, so what do you mean by "sorting"?

Comment: @Bergi: You know that's not true anymore. :-) (In real-world use, even the operations that aren't required to follow the order do so on all major JavaScript engines.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder On all JS engines but not all JS transpilers

Comment: @slebetman: Quite. Like any other language feature, you need to be aware of what can and can't be polyfilled or transformed if transpiling for older engines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because (as you said) of the numeric keys (or to use the spec's term, *integer indexes**).

[`Object.assign`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.assign) works in the order defined by `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`, which for ordinary objects is the [`OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) abstract operation, which lists the properties in a defined order (integer indexes first, then other string-named properties in order of creation, then Symbol-named properties in order of creation). The resulting object's properties will be enumerated (by operations that follow the defined order) in the same way, and so, integer indexes, numerically, followed by other properties in creationg order.

If your keys weren't integer indexes, you could control the order of the result by pre-creating the properties in the order you wanted them, but not in the case of integer index keys.

So for instance, if your keys were `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, you could determine the order the resulting object's properties were listed (for operations that follow the order):

```js
const x = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
const y = {c: 'c', d: 'd'};
const result1 = Object.assign({c: null, d: null, a: null, b: null}, x, y);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result1));
const result2 = Object.assign({c: null, d: null, a: null, b: null}, y, x);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result2));
const result3 = Object.assign({a: null, b: null, c: null, d: null}, x, y);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result3));
const result4 = Object.assign({a: null, b: null, c: null, d: null}, y, x);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result4));
```

Note that I'm using `JSON.stringify` there for output, because `JSON.stringify` is defined to follow property order (whereas `for-in` and `Object.keys` are not).

But not for your keys, which are integer indexes.

If order is important, usually an object is the wrong data structure; instead, you'd want an array. Arrays are also objects and some of the ordered-ness of an array is just convention (barring optimization), but they have several important order-specific features, not least the `length` property and their various methods that work in a defined order.

---

* "integer index" is defined [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type):

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2<sup>53</sup>-1.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think I should use an additional ordered array for my case.